# trouble recognizing \ as a character

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm making a syntax analyzer for school that reads a c++ test file in scheme and outputs another in html with the program now colored based on their id. However, I'm having trouble with it recognizing the `\` as a character. The teacher said we don't have to worry about respecting the formatting, so line breaks and indents aren't necessary. Here is my code as well as the test file:

```
#lang racket

(require 2htdp/batch-io)

;shortcuts
(define htmlformat "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'> <title>output.html</title> </head> <body>")
(define htmlformat2 "</body> </html>")
(define number "<span class='number'>")
(define specials "<span class='special'>")
(define ids "<span class='identifier'>")
(define reserved "<span class='reserved'>")
(define comments "<span class='comment'>")
(define libraries "<span class='library'>")
(define endspan "</span>")

;opens input file
(define infile "test.cpp")

;read input file
;char by char
(define file->list-of-chars
  (lambda (filename)
    (flatten
     (map string->list
          (read-1strings filename)))))

;char to strings, shows up in reverse order
(define list-of-chars->list-of-strings
  (lambda (loc aux result)
    (cond
      [(empty? loc) result]
      [(char-whitespace? (car loc))
       (list-of-chars->list-of-strings (cdr loc)
                                       '()
                                       (cons
                                        (list->string aux)
                                        result))]
      [(char-punctuation? (car loc))
       (list-of-chars->list-of-strings (cdr loc)
                                       '()
                                       (cons
                                        (list->string
                                         (cons (car loc) '()))
                                        (cons
                                         (list->string aux)
                                         result)))]
      [else
       (list-of-chars->list-of-strings (cdr loc)
                                       (append aux (cons (car loc) '()))
                                       result)])))

; char to list of strings, shows up in corret order
(define file->list-of-strings
  (lambda (filename)
    (reverse
     (list-of-chars->list-of-strings
      (file->list-of-chars infile) '() '()))))

(define lst (file->list-of-strings infile))

;regex matching
(define match
  (λ (strng)
    (cond
      [(regexp-match #rx"^[+-]?([0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*|\\.[0-9]+)$" strng) (string-append number strng endspan)]
      [(equal? strng "<iostream>") (string-append libraries "<" endspan libraries "iostream" endspan libraries ">" endspan)] 
      [(regexp-match #rx"^\\<(.)+\\>$" strng) (string-append libraries "strng" endspan)]
      [(regexp-match #rx"^(asm|double|new|switch|auto|else|operator|template|break|enum|private|this|case|extern|printf|protected|throw|catch|float|public|try|char|for|register|typedef|class|friend|return|union|const|goto|short|unsigned|continue|if|signed|virtual|default|inline|sizeof|void|delete|int|static|volatile|do|long|struct|while)+$" strng) (string-append reserved strng endspan)]
      [(regexp-match #rx"^([A-Z]|[a-z]|\\_)(.)*$" strng) (string-append ids strng endspan)]
      [(regexp-match #rx"^(\\#|\\[|\\]|\\{|\\}|\\+|\\-|\\/|\\<|\\>|\\<=|\\>=|\\=|\\(|\\)|\\*|\\'|\\;|\\!|\\$|\\%|\\^|\\&|\\?|\"|\\||,)$" strng) (string-append specials strng endspan)]
      [(regexp-match #rx"^\\//(.)*$" strng) (string-append comments strng endspan)]
      [else ""])))

;applies match to all elements of a list of strings
(define mapp
  (λ (lst)
    (cond
      [(null? lst) '()]
      [else (cons (match (car lst))(mapp (cdr lst)))])))

;assigns html format to list of strings
(define htmlList (mapp lst))

; list of strings to single string
(define list-of-strings->string
  (lambda (strlst)
    (string-join strlst " ")))
;; usage example
;; (define strlst (file->list-of-strings input-filename))
;; (list-of-strings->string strlst)

; converts list of strings to a single string
(define singlestring (list-of-strings->string htmlList))

;creates output file
(define outfile "output.html")

;creates single string adding html header and footer
(define finalstring (string-append htmlformat singlestring htmlformat2))

;writes everything into output file
(write-file outfile finalstring)
```

test code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%i", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to recognize backslash? In a regular expression you have to escape it to match it literally.

Comment: Note that `#include <iostream>` is not required to provide a prototype for `printf`. The correct directive would be `#include <stdlib.h>`. And with that, the code is purely C, and shouldn't be tagged C++.

Comment: I'd venture myself to say that, in the `;regex matching` section, where you seem to define the tokens that you can parse in a C++ file, you are detecting numbers, library names, reserved words, ids, special characters that can appear in language expressions (`*`, `?`, and so on), and `//` comments, but you are missing string literals such as `"\n"`. Having said that, I can't understand how your code doesn't fail to recognize `"%i"` as well.

Comment: *"I'm having trouble with it recognizing the ``\`` as a character."* -- what sort of trouble? Everything looks like ``\``? Nothing looks like ``\``? Somewhere in between? What is your expected and actual output? Why is your test code more than one line? A file consisting of the line `char tab = '\t';` is all you need to get a backslash in C++ code; keep your test case as simple as possible. (Similarly, you probably don't need to output a full HTML document to demonstrate the issue -- just something that produces output demonstrating that ``\`` is problematic. See [mre].)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[(char-whitespace? (car loc))
 ...]
[(eqv? (car loc) #\\)
 ...]
```

to recognize backslash.

Note: `#\a` means the character `a` and thus `#\\` means the character `\`.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean "recognize \"?

You can "escape the escape code" by using "\\"

```cpp
printf("\\");
```

That should print "\".

If you want to print 2, you can do `printf("\\\\")`... it goes on.

Other than that, I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you don't understand a question, it is more appropriate to wait for clarification than to try to answer. Until you have enough rep to post a comment requesting clarification, you might have to hope others request the clarification, or you could simply move on to a better-asked question.

Comment: I believe the question is asking how to do something in Scheme, rather than in C++. The C++ code is just the input. *(I've updated the question's tags since both C++ and HTML are just formats used, not core to the question. Realistically, the question should have been simplified to just recognizing a backslash character, with no need to explain the full assignment. But we have what we have.)*